# Product List in Custom Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

So, I'm fairly new to Customization in Dynamics CRM and I've run into an issue. I've created an entity called 'Projects' that works fairly similarly to 'Quotes'. The entity Quotes contains a 'Products' list view where you can add, create, etc products in this view; I'm trying to recreate that in Projects. Is there a simple way to do this?

What I've tried so far is: I've noticed that Quotes is paired up with an entity called 'Quotes Products', so I've tried creating a 'Project Products' entity and created a relationship between the two similar to the relationship between Quotes and Quotes Products. I've then gone through and tried to recreate all the fields that Quotes has inside Projects in order to pair with Products, but I can't create Field type of 'Unique Identifier' like the ones Quotes has.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: At a basic level this functionality is driven by jscript running on the quote form and it should be technically possible to create similar logic for any subgrid.  However it is not something that is trivial to do with custom entities and relationships.. you will not be able to create a Project Products entity and just throw up an editable Project Products subgrid on the project form.  The most straightforward solution here is to relate projects to quotes and use the out of the box quote functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are triyng to do is create N:N relationship between Products and Projects, You started good with creating Project product entity now you need to create lookup to product on Project product entity and youre good to go.

@Zach is right about the editable grid the whole thing sucks anyway.